# mongooseJS return number of IDs in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongooseJS as a mongoDB driver in Javascript. I can return the number of fields in the database with the following code:

```
app.get('/total/', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  boxmac.count().then((macdb) => {
    res.send({macdb});

  }, (e) => {
    res.status(404).send(e)
    console.log(e);

  });
});
```

Which when I load the file with node, and query the resulting link, I get

```
{
  "macdb": 2108
}
```

However I'm trying to return the number of Unique ID's in the collection (should be 168-170). I've tried placing the id in various places (such as count({id}).then, but can't get the number of ID's.

here's my model:

```
var boxmac = mongoose.model('macdbs', {
  ProductName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  },
  OriginCountry: {
    type: String,
    default: false
  },

  StoreBrand: {
    type: String,
    default: null
  },

  Type: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: true
  },
  Pasta: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false
  },
  ADC: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false
  },
  PastaType: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false
  },
  Org: {
    type: String,
    default: 'N',
    required: false
  },
  Veg: {
    type: String,
    default: 'N',
    required: false
  },
  Mic: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false
  },
  Exp: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false
  },
  PriceRaw: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false
  },
  SauceType: {
    type: String,
    default: 'dry',
    required: true
  },
  BoxSize: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: true
  },
  EpNo: {
    type: Number,
    default: null,
    required: true
  },
  URL: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: true
  },
  Price: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: true
  },
  Rating: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false
  },
  Comments: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false
  }
});
```

Comment: can you show your schema?

Comment: if schema is the same as model

Comment: which unique ids you want to retrieve?

Comment: I'm trying to use _ID, however I'd be happy with just using any item in the model since they should only be in once per object.

Comment: `_id` are unique in any document. So you can just count total documents, it will give you the answer.